# complex generic type constraint and type inferrance

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

I am trying to build a micro ORM in TypeScript, but I am facing this compilation issue:

```ts
Type 'TObject' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [k in k]: object; }'.
  Type 'object' is not assignable to type '{ [k in k]: object; }'.
```

Would anyone know why this code sample throws a compilation error? and how to fix it?

```ts
type NavigationProperties<T, TKey extends keyof T> = T[TKey] extends object ? TKey : never;
 type Relationship<T extends { [k in TMember]: TTarget }, TMember extends keyof T, TTarget extends object = object> = {
    name: TMember,
    isComposite?: boolean,
};
class A<TObject extends object>
{
    public readonly relationships: Partial<{ [k in NavigationProperties<TObject, keyof TObject>]: Relationship<TObject, k> }> = { }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgNwJYHM7CQewHYAUBOmk+GEAzgDwAqANFFQNIQhQQAewE2AJmVANbNMAM3oA+KAF56AbUbMAuqw5deUTACMAVhADGwKAH56TFgC4o2CAgj4A3ACgooSFABKEADbos2MgAskMGplTh4+AG8oGX4oJGx6AFkIAFsNWwULKio4fBQIAwBfOipktNtQ1T5BEBF6Epy8gsrw9W09A2lNHX0JaQinKCHsOBSILLL0-BpBoaQyAGFMFLBMMiROQwsNTExPCDhsGcLHXW8yPgBBagB5dv0WtW6OsQcBoaGwAFcNTyRdKD4A7cHCeFhA7wYHABIJkCy4XIYOCeChRGJxBLwZBoKF4QjEUiUKh3HrAOg1OrE+7AMSZdxeHzQwLBKmk8kSQp9KBRQoOQpAA)

**Edit**

As requested by Shivam, I am adding more context to it: I also want to make it work when I have mixed types or non-matching types:
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgNwJYHM7CQewHYAUBOmk+GEAzgDwAqANFFQNIQhQQAewE2AJmVANbNMAM3oA+KAF56AbUbMAuqw5deUTACMAVhADGwKAH56TFgC4o2CAgj4A3ACgHoSPQDy2vcGrLOPPpo6+nRUVODQ7H5qgV4S0gDeUDIMUEjYsIio6Fh4hMSklLQCQqJUYgoWoeFQAL5OLtAAShAANtk4ZAAWSGA+kap8VB5B3kVVkGIhpnz9-sUgIvQhYa6z0Z76cVDxDlB7lnAAthCV0zS7+0hkAMKYh2CYZEichhYamJgtEHDY5zWOzmqzTaGA63TAhV8A3cG1Gy3Ck3oKwiKjmMU2Um2Fz2yVS6XgyDQoNyRFsBWodEEC1K5VeUGB7WwXR6FKgDHhEwcdQcujaZD4AEE+qi1ENYazxhBEZKoWjYZj0cAJDt9lAwABXDQtJC6KD4b7cHAtFj6kE5ZkQiwM4kWwocqWYxJ1bkAehdyiOYC+UHVZDgKAggNcAFkQMjHdi1XkAIwWbDqw4aWyRh74MAAJgsZGA+DSKC59WqAA0I6q4BZQ8jIxoK2HwpHdFmc3mCw5uHo2vqoLoOgZAhYhUWxG2O3Auz2mX3tJmoELKwinIEAHSmxm2qBuqANVJ8a3m8GUIt0RXDhyb7eLQLRletNcHpdwHf02828EUI9QABEcE-x9hw+XVdXx6MgH0MJdsCOaBN2-T8HEAl99xApcNHAyDjg3d1Pw0T8gA)

Comment: Post the error message too

Comment: `NavigationProperties` resolve to `never` if any key of `T` does not extend `object`. Is it intentional?

Comment: Yes, that is intentional if my type does not contain any relationship/navigation property.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

In type `Relationship`, `T` was constraint to `{ [k in TMember]: TTarget }`, while declaring property `relationships`, `TObject`  is passed which has type `object` which is supertype of `{ [k in TMember]: TTarget }`. Thus the incompatibility.

### Solution

```
type NavigationProperties<T, TKey extends keyof T> = T[TKey] extends object ? TKey : never;

type TObject<T extends object, TType extends object> = { [K in keyof T]: TType }

type Relationship<T extends TObject<T, TType>, TKeys extends keyof T, TType extends object> = {
    name: TKeys,
    isComposite?: boolean,
};

type Relationships<T extends TObject<T, TType>, TType extends object> = {
    [K in NavigationProperties<T, keyof T>]?: Relationship<T, K, TType>
}

class A<T extends TObject<T, TType>, TType extends object = object> {
    public readonly relationships: Relationships<T, TType> = { }
}

// example usage
type MyType = {
    prop1: number
    porp2: string
}

type X = {
    a: MyType
    b: MyType
}

declare const obj: A<X>

obj.relationships // type is Relationships<X, object>

// type of obj1.relationships.a is Relationship<X, "a", object>
obj.relationships.a?.name // "a"
obj.relationships.b?.name // "b"

declare const obj1: A<X, MyType>

obj1.relationships // type is Relationships<X, MyType>

// type of obj1.relationships.a is Relationship<X, "a", MyType>
obj1.relationships.a?.name // "a"
obj1.relationships.b?.name // "b"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcghgNwJYHM7CQewHYAUBOmk+GEAzgDwAqANFFQNIQhQQAewE2AJmVANbNMAM3oA+KAF56AbUbMAuqw5deUTACMAVhADGwKAH56TFgC4o2CAgj4A3ACgHoSPQDy2vcGrLOPPpo6+nRUVODQ7H5qgV4S0gDeUDIMUEjYAkKiVAoWoeFQAL5OLtAAShAANuhY2GQAFkhgPpGqfFQeQd609GGQYiGmfC3+GSAi9CG9ESojMfpxUPEOUCuWcAC2ELmDNMurSGQAwpjrYJhkSJyGFhqYmBUQcNi7BY7O+eVVGDj1jZRUvla7k8+mok3C-R6+WG0RBwAWS1WSRSaVgiFQ1RwBCItlI-zogjGWTECmuUE+mNqDSa3QY4L6DiKDl0VTIfAAgs0Zmp2nCwVC+vTplEAnCpOo4RJEaswABXDQVJC6KD4R7cHAVFiqr41X5gMgWCnfKl-fl5PrixJFJkAehtyg2YAeUFlZDgKAg71cAFkQFNLXsVmBCGAAIwWbCy9YaWyBqBnfBgABMFjIwHwaRQjOK+QAGgGkXALL6pnGNMW-eFsw5uHoqqqoLofgZAhZObmxE5AgA6bWUvV8O1QEqpPhG3XUyi5uhzeFOIcj8aBUO9yr9yfduCj8lr416ijTqAAIjgR5nkocPb7e43cEM3ewG2gQ5PR8v2lXOp+G4098fmygF8NDfGs6zgBsm1qFttHDKB2zoEsIS7GDP3XP5APtEcDh3L8TX1A8EMrBkHAXfIlxQ68Jz+Tdt3Hb9GgI49T0IqZO2XVCb2ou8HyfDCmLfdjKPo-Vu1-HiAKAo8gA)

Comment: This is almost perfect. However, it breaks if the type does not have any relationship or if X would be a mix of relationship and non relationship. This is what I tried to achieve with the never option.

Comment: @NicolasPenin Please write an example for the same.